# What does Dominate Mind do?

Tags: star-wars-kotor

In the first Knights of the Old Republic (KotOR) there are three ways to improve your dialogue options, i.e. get people to do what you want them to do without using the good ol' glowstick:

- The [**Persuade** skill](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic/Skills#Persuade) can be leveled up to improve your chances of passing the common *[Persuade]* dialogue options.
- The [**Affect Mind** force power](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic/Force_powers#Affect_Mind) can be chosen to unlock additional dialogue options through Jedi persuasion techniques. Comes up in the dialogue as *[Affect Mind]*:

  > Affect and Dominate Mind enable persuasive use of the Force. Once a Jedi has this power, extra options will appear in conversations as appropriate. Success is not guaranteed for extreme commands or if the target is strong willed.
- Then there is the **Dominate Mind** force power, which is the upgrade of *Affect Mind*:

  > Dominate Mind is more powerful than Affect Mind, and very few beings can resist its effects. This power does not affect droids. Only the main player character can select this power during level-up.

As you can see, the description for *Dominate Mind* is very vague. My understanding was that it simply improved the existing *[Affect Mind]* dialogue options in a way to work in some cases where *Affect Mind* would fail. But this is only speculation. So my question:

- **What *exactly* does Dominate Mind do that Affect Mind won't?** Are there any concrete examples where Affect Mind fails and Dominate Mind succeeds?
- **Does Dominate Mind unlock additional dialogue options anywhere in the game?** If so, where?

Basically I am trying to determine if there is any reason to get this force power, or what it actually does. Most discussions I came across were based on hearsay and speculation, so it would be nice to get some facts on this.

Answer (score 6):

It has been some time since I've played KOTOR. While I don't have any concrete examples, I did some comparison between Affect Mind and Dominate Mind a few years back while trying to optimize my build. I did many playthroughs at the time and even made some fairly successful attempts at speedrunning the game. Here is generally what I found:

- Affect Mind and Dominate Mind both unlock the same dialog options. I wasn't able to find any dialog that only appeared with Dominate Mind.
- Affect Mind works by chance, while Dominate Mind either works or it doesn't. It appeared through my playthroughs that Affect Mind could sometimes fail, while the same options with Dominate Mind never failed.
- Some dialog options may *require* Dominate Mind to succeed. There were a few times that I could never get it to work with Affect Mind, but Dominate Mind succeeded.

All-in-all I found it worth taking Dominate Mind because those extra dialog options can be rather useful.

Comment: That's the most conclusive answer I got so far, so thank you for that. I still would like to know what the dialogues are where affect mind will always fail but dominate won't. Otherwise it seems like a pretty useless power, considering that you don't really unlock something new.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the dialog.tlk file there is only 1 (!) instance where [dominate mind] is used.

It's during the conversation with the injured "Major Hurka of the Sith's Second battalion"

Here is the entry (from the .tlk converted to xml)

-Table1-
    -index-16973-/index-
    -Text-[Dominate Mind] I'm not the enemy. I'm your friend. You want to help me.-/Text-
    -SoundRef-*m40abinjo08019*-/SoundRef-
  -/Table1-

Once again: it is the only entry in the dialog.tlk file. 
Maybe it's used in another way (through .mod or .dlg files that are put in override?)